# Moving into collective SVN and using jarn.mkrelease

Tags: python, svn, plone, pypi

I've got a product, currently available here:

http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/RestrictedSize.RestrictedSize/

And I'm trying to use jarn.mkrelease to release an egg.

However, I get this message when running mkrelease:

```
~/demo$ PYTHONPATH=mkrelease/ ./mkrelease/bin/mkrelease -d pypi NBF/src/RestrictedSize/
Releasing RestrictedSize 1.0
Sending        NBF/src/RestrictedSize/setup.py
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 246625.
Tagging RestrictedSize 1.0
URL must point to trunk, branch, or tag: https://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/RestrictedSize.RestrictedSize
```

The RestrictedSize directory used, is a checkout of

http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/RestrictedSize.RestrictedSize/

I think I screwed up the SVN import into the collective somehow, so I need someone to delete RestrictedSize and RestrictedSize.RestrictedSize from SVN and point me to some tutorial or help me here.  :)

Comment: To clean up, create a directory 'trunk' in your checkout, then move all files into that directory (`svn add trunk`, then `svn mv * trunk`, you'll get an error message about trunk not being movable into itself).

Answer (score 3):

That's because the standard for svn directory structure is:

```
<myproduct>
    /branches
    /tags
    /trunk
```

and that product expects exactly that structure. You should move all the code in a new trunk directory and than add also branches and tags.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I found the Howto here BTW: http://plone.org/documentation/kb/create-a-new-project-in-the-plone-collective